# Remote desktop group is missing in remote tab in Windows 8

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-8-preview

Under Windows 8 (latest Windows 8 Release Preview) System properties → Remote, the "remote desktop" group is missing.

This group is where you define which RDP clients are allowed to connect to your system. This anomaly prevents me from defining a RDP host on this machine.

I am looking for the cause of this thing. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Windows 8 or Windows 8 Pro. Windows 8 Pro has Remote Desktop Server feature not Windows 8.

Comment: Are you a full admin on the box?

Comment: First, what happens if you create the group yourself? Second, upgrade to the official version now that it's out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions :

Windows 8 Pro is comparable to Windows 7 Professional and Ultimate and is targeted towards enthusiasts and business users; it includes all the features of Windows 8. Additional features include the ability to receive Remote Desktop connections

This means that the windows 8 version (non pro) is unable to receive RDP connection.

Comment: =(             ................

Answer (score -1):

You can use [rdpwrap](https://github.com/binarymaster/rdpwrap) to enable it. From project description:

> The goal of this project is to enable Remote Desktop Host support and concurrent RDP sessions on reduced functionality systems for home usage.
>
> RDP Wrapper works as a layer between Service Control Manager and Terminal Services, so the original termsrv.dll file remains untouched. Also this method is very strong against Windows Update.

Here's [link to releases](https://github.com/binarymaster/rdpwrap/releases) where you can download latest version, installation is as easy as running `install.bat`. Then you can configure your remote access with included `RDPConf.exe`